# Get user email with fb sdk for .net in win 8 store app

Tags: windows, facebook, sdk, windows-store-apps

In my Win 8 store app I am using fb sdk for .net for authentication and I need to get the user's email linked with facebook.

I am invoking this function

```
dynamic result = await fb.GetTaskAsync("me");
```

Result consists of 12 different fields such as id, name, cityId and so on, but there is no email field.
I want to ask, if it is possible to access the email of user which is linked with his facebook account.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the extended permission email, then you can get the email from the me field. You can always test your calls here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/